# Compare files in List<FileInfo> using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, file, compare

I have 2 collections of files as `List<FileInfo>`. I am currently using 2 x `foreach` to loop through each set and match the files (shown below). Is there a quicker way to do this in LINQ and `.RemoveAt` when found.?

- I need the filenames and file lengths to match.

  ```
          var sdinfo = new DirectoryInfo(srcPath);
          var ddinfo = new DirectoryInfo(dstPath);

          var sFiles = new List<FileInfo>(sdinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
          var dFiles = new List<FileInfo>(ddinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));

          foreach (var sFile in sFiles)
          {
              bool foundFile = false;
              int i = 0;

              foreach (var dFile in dFiles)
              {
                  if (sFile.Name == dFile.Name && sFile.Length == dFile.Length)
                  {
                      foundFile = true;
                      dFiles.RemoveAt(i);
                  }
                  i += 1;
              }
          }
  ```

Cheers.

Comment: I'm assuming there is a typo in your sample code.   sdinfo and ddinfo both use srcPath.  See lines 1 and 2

Comment: Yep thats a Type-O. Good spot, cheers. EDITED.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`Enumerable.Except<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
private class FileInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    public bool Equals(FileInfo x, FileInfo y)
    {
        return x == null ? y == null : (x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.Length == y.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}

sFiles = sFiles.Except(dFiles, new FileInfoComparer()).ToList();
```

In the example above you get all files from `sFiles` that are absent in the `dFiles`.

Comment: The OP asked for a faster solution that two for loops.  Does LINQ have a different algorithm for Except()?  I realize it is fewer lines of code.   I'm curious about performance.

Comment: @KC-NH The `Except` method uses the `Set` class (internal implementation of hash set): [LINQ source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#e289e6c98881b2b8#references).

Answer (score 1):

for one, this code will throw an exception if executed, because you're modifying an enumeration (dFiles) while iterating through it. This is easily solved by using the [`ToList()` method](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tolist%20method) however, in order to copy the enumeration. This will also have an issue because you increment your index regardless of removal, which can also cause an error - the colloquial off-by-one-exception.

If you're worried about speed, don't be. Linq uses methods which use foreach and yield returns, and are mostly visible in source from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs).

If you want to make the code easier to read, then this is where Linq becomes useful. For one, there is the [`.Join()` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
foreach(var fileToRemove in sFiles.Join(dFiles, s => s, d => d, (s, d) => s).ToArray())
    dFiles.Remove(fileToRemove);
```

Assuming you're iterating through dList afterwards, you can also use [`.Except(...)` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var files = sdinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Except(ddinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

finally, if you need to KEEP sFiles, the following code wraps it all together

```
List<string> sFiles, dFiles;
dFiles = ddinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Except(sFiles = sdinfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Comment: This looks useful. Basically, if there is one that doesn't match or is missing, I return false on the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trade space for time, you could build a hash set of one list, and the lookup each element of the other in the hash set.  Lookups are O(1) whereas the loop is O(n)